# Remove column from stacked bar plot

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

```
df4
  Year Jan Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct Nov Dec
1 2011 742 796 1210 1376 1885 1824 1943 1933 1321 1013 816 785
2 2012 902 879 1227 1232 1650 1843 2015 1930 1143 1065 826 785
3 2013 763 725  990 1360 1581 1579 1999 1821 1229  940 709 679
4 2014 785 717 1062 1294 1682 1806 1962 1845 1280 1001 673 785
5 2015 739 730 1160 1344 1663 1927 2184 1855   NA   NA  NA  NA

barplot(as.matrix(df4))
```

[image]

I get this stacked bar plot but I don't want "Year" to be another bar, I want "Year" to be erased, so that Jan bar starts first, can anyone help me?

Comment: please see the image, and my title is wrong, its about stacked bar plot

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
barplot(as.matrix(df4[,-1]))
```

The `,-1` keep all rows but strips the first column from the data frame.

[image]